# I am trying to find derivative $f$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> I want to find the derivative of $f: [1, \infty] \to 
> \mathbb{R}$ defined by formula
>   $$f(x) = \int_0^{x^4} e^{t^2} dt$$

---

Here is what I have done:

---

$F(b) = \int_0^b  e^{t^2} dt$ and knowing that $f(x) = F(x^4)$

So I take

We want $\frac d{dx} f(x) = \frac d{dx}F(x^4) * \frac d{dx} x^4 = 4x^3 * e^{{(x^4)}^2} = 4x^3 e{^x}^8$

Where $F'(x^4) = e^{{x^4}^2}$ since $F'(x^4) = f'(x^4)$

> Is since $F'(x^4) = f'(x^4)$ correct logic for that step?

Comment: Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the chain rule.

Comment: Yes, you have ! And then ?

Comment: !!! ??? !?!?!? !!??

Comment: A simpler example to convince you that $e^{t^2}$ is not the derivative. Let $g(x) = \int_0^{x^2} \cos t dt$. According to you, the derivative of $g$ is $\cos t$? Let's see. $g(x) = \int_0^{x^2} \cos t dt = \left[\sin t\right]_0^{x^2} = \sin x^2$. So $g'(x) = 2x\cos x^2 \ne \cos t$. Do you see the difference?

Comment: downvotes, oh noez!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Consider $$f(x) = \int_0^{y} e^{t^2} dt$$ where $y$ is a function of $x$ and, as David Mitra wrote, use the FTC and the chain rule.

Comment: Not at all ! Please read Siminore's answer once more.

Comment: For the record, you're probably getting downvotes because people don't like exclamation marks in question titles. Especially multiple exclamation marks.

Comment: @user18921 Oh okay, thank you for that. I will avoid using them, even though I feel a sense of urgency due to my anxiety disorder.

Comment: @user151558, no worries. This actually brings up an important issue, which is that some aspects of this website might be distressing to some people (not saying this is you).

Comment: @user151558, by the way, another "neat trick" for avoiding downvotes is to avoid the [imperative mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood). So instead of writing "Find so-and-so, here's what I've done." (which is an imperative), I tend to write "I'm trying to find so-and-so, here's what I've done."

Comment: @user18921 Thank you very much for your kind advice. I will definitely take this into account for all of my future questions.

Comment: @user151558, glad to help. For the record, I don't mind if you don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $F(z)=\int_0^z e^{t^2}\, dt$ and remark that $f(x)=F(x^4)$. Hence
$$
Df(x) = DF(x^4) Dx^4 = 4x^3 e^{(x^4)^2} = 4x^3 e^{x^8}.
$$

Comment: This seems correct. Now why is $F'(x^4) = e^{{x^4}^2}$? Is that because $F'(b) = f(b)$ FTC?

Comment: $F'(t)=e^{t^2}$ since $F$ is a primitive of $f$. Then you insert $t=x^4$.

Comment: Yes, I see now. Thank you.